# Outlook Addin - CommandBar Issue in Outlook 2013

Tags: outlook, add-in, commandbar

I have Outlook Addin Developed in visual Studio 2003. its using CommandBar for adding Addin Tab and menu for my Addin. it is working properly till Outlook 2010,but its not running in Outlook 2013, due to CommandBar issues.

I have debuged the Addin with outlook 2013.CommandBarControls not working in outlook 2013.

When my addin reach the following statement, outlook 2013 throws an exceptionatlcomcil.h - Debug Assertion Error.

SpCmdCtrl = spCmdBar-> FindControl(vMenuEmpty, vMenuID);
SpCmdCtrl is getting {0x00000000}.

I wonder why findControl() is not returning something.
The statement is working fine in Previous versions of Outlook.

Any Help is deeply Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2013 doesn't allow you to work with commandbars.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj229903.aspx

Regards,
Victor

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Signatures are considered bad form. Please refer to the FAQ for more details.

Comment: Is there any way, i can still use CommandBar, bcz my addin is developed in visual studio 2003 - ATL/C++. and i am not sure about IRibbon by implementing "IRibbonExtensibility is possible in VS 2003.